# How can I prove the existence of a linear operator based on injection?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional, $U$ is a subspace of $V$, and $S \in L(U,V)$. Prove that there exists an invertible operator $T \in L(V, V)$, such that $T(u) = S(u)$ for every $u \in U$ if and only if $S$ is injective.

---

I started by taking a basis $B$ of $U$ = {$u_1,...,u_m$}, and expanding it with {$u_{m+1}, ...u_{n}$} such that it is a basis for the entire space $V$.

Then, I was going to use the Identity map $I$, as the map $T$ that I have to prove exists, but this didn't work out. I'm not sure how else to approach this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that $T \in L(v)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a basis $\{ u_1, \dots, u_m \}$ for $U$, which can be extended to a basis  $\{ u_1, \dots, u_m , u_{m+1}, \dots, u_n \}$ for the whole of $V$.

Now consider the elements $$  v_1 := S(u_1), \ \ \dots \ \ , v_m := S(u_m ).$$
Can you use the injectivity of $S$ to show that $\{ v_1, \dots, v_m \}$ is a linearly independent set, and hence, can be extended to a basis $\{ v_1, \dots, v_m, v_{m + 1}, \dots, v_n \}$ for $V$?

To define $T : V \to V$, the idea is to map $$u_1 \mapsto v_1, \ \ \dots, \ \ u_n \mapsto v_n .$$ Can you use this idea to define a linear map $V \to V$? And can you show that this linear map is bijective (hence invertible), and agrees with $S$ on the subspace $U$?

Comment: A slight complication that your argument nicely handles is that $S$ needn't map $U$ into itself. Thus you need to both extend a basis for $U$ into a basis of $V$ and you also need to extend a basis of $S(U)$ into a basis of $V$. This is the only reason why the idea proposed by the OP of defining $T$ to be the identity on the span of $\{ u_{m+1},\dots,u_n \}$ doesn't work.

Comment: @Ian exactly! :) And well explained.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I understand most of it but I don't know how to define the linear operator from $V \to V$. Im new to this so please bear with me...

Comment: @Jaigus The definition is $T(\sum_i a_i u_i) = \sum_i a_i v_i$.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know what was considered the "official definition".